# Print duplicate values from CSV file including occurence count

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

Example input is

```
John,Yes,123
Tom,No,345
Jason,Yes,567
Thomas,No,123
Jess,No,999
James,Yes,888
Lisa,No,345
Lou,Yes,777
Peter,No,123
```

I want to print the occurence count of the values in the 3rd column, but only those that occur more than one. So for the above example, the desired output would be:

```
3 123
2 345
```

How do we do this with `sed`/`awk` or something similar?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. (You could use tools like `sort`, `cut` and `uniq`, or you could solve the whole thing with `awk`. There are answers here using `awk` to find duplicate lines that could be adapted to find duplicate fields.)

Answer (score 4):

```
cut -f3 -d, "$file" | sort | uniq -cd | sed 's/  *//'
```

- `cut` uses a comma as the delimiter and outputs only the third field
- `sort` sorts the lines so `uniq` can be used
- `uniq -c` counts how many consecutive duplicate lines there are, `-d` makes it output only the duplicates (i.e. omit the unique values)
- the last `sed` removes the leading spaces.

Answer (score 2):

An `awk` one-liner:

```
awk -F',' '{c[$3]++} END{for (i in c) {if (c[i]>1) print c[i],i}}' input.csv
```

- This instructs `awk` to use `,` as field separator.
- For every line, it will increase a counter for the value of the third field (`$3`).
- At the end, it will iterate over all "indices" registered in the counter array `c` (`for (i in c)`), and if the "entry" associated with that index is larger than one, print the occurence count and the corresponding value of the third column.

If you want finer control over output formatting, you may want to use `printf` instead of `print` in the `END` block.